# use php fb application on more than one website

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hi alla i developed a facebook application with php and I use it on my website.
A customer of mine tried this application and wants to integrate it into his website. Is there a way to share my fb app from my website without create a new app and clone the existing one ?

If possible I prefer to avoid javascript

Thanks in advance

Comment: If the other site is on a different domain, then it's not possible to use the same app-id. Even otherwise, it's generally advisable not to share fb app-ids between different sites. The insights will get messed up, among other things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. But just create a new fb app for your customer, copy the code to his site, and change the app_id and app_secret.  And then you'll have a clone of the app on his site with his own app_id.

If you try to run the same app_id on different domains, you'll get this error message from FB when you attempt to init the SDK:

"Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.:
One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.
It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be
a subdomain of one of the App's domains."

Note that the website's domain (example.com) is defined in your app settings in the FB [App Dashboard](https://developers.facebook.com/apps).

If you try to configure his-domain.com in the Basic section of your app settings, you'll get this error:  "Error: his-domain.com must be derived from one of: Site URL, Mobile Site URL, Canvas URL, Secure Canvas URL, Page Tab URL or Secure Page Tab URL"

Comment: So can't i use that if I embed this in a I frame?

Comment: You can try embedding your app on his site with an iframe. Let us know if it works.   I haven't tried

Comment: i'm a bit late, but better than never. It didn't work... we built a new application for the target